# Multi-page faces-messaging, good practise

Tags: java, jsf-2

As far as I know the only working way for using faces-messages through several pages is to use custom PhaseListener which provide save/restore messages through requests. 
I'm talking about something like [this](http://ocpsoft.org/java/persist-and-pass-facesmessages-over-page-redirects/).

But is it a good practise?

What other variants can be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern is one of best practices to design your web application navigation flow. As you're using JSF 2, passing messages from one request to another is quite straight forward [using the flash scope](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/07/learning-jsf2-using-flash-scope/). This scope is similar to a session map, however its life is limited from one request to the next one, after that is being removed. Also there are some third party libraries as **omnifaces** [which implement](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Messages) the functionality for you.